# Alternative US INTL keyboard layout which is not "clever" with the quotes?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I'm using the US International keyboard layout in Windows 10 because I need a US layout for easily accessible "programming" keys (<,>,[,],(,),|,;, and so on..) together with the ability to write German umlauts ('ä', 'ö','ü', 'ß', ...)

Now I learned that Microsoft uses the "US International" layout to demonstrate it's superior cleverness and cripples fluent writing by introducing smart braces.

Trying to write `"US"` results in `ÜS`, writing back ticks, single quotes and double quotes behave differently, and there are many more features which make it impossible to seamlessly switch between systems with "US international" keyboard layout installed.

Answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/346142/my-windows-keyboard-is-being-clever-with-the-quote-keys-how-can-i-stop-it) question suggest to just switch to "US" layout. But that way I don't have the "US INTL" layout anymore of course.

Are there alternatives? Can I deactivate this "feature"? (I just realized that trying to write a double quote even behaves differently the second time I try it!)

@Microsoft: Thanks, this is just as useful as Notepad, the Middle-Mouse-Button-Navigator and the CapsLock key (which I know is not your invention)

Comment: It happens in Windows and any other OS. When we use "US International" AND we need special characters for the our non-English input language we take advantage of the "dead keys" feature. That means if you want double-quotes you need to press the key once followed by space. Not using the space will be interpreted as "dead key" and accentuate the next character typed resulting in an umlaut. It's just a matter of adapting your typing technique like I did - I use a few US Int keyboard for languages like Spanish, Portuguese and French.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - you ought to make that an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin OK, done.

Comment: Thank you - cos I just didn't know that. I use Eng Intl when remoting into PCs from my Mac, which puts my @ and " keys back in the 'right place' for me, which leads to this dead key issue. Now fixed, tyvm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [US International without dead keys layout Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1133440/us-international-without-dead-keys-layout-windows-10)

Comment: Probably - but I cannot check any more. What helped me a lot was uninstalling Windows and installing Fedora. Now my keyboard works as intended.

Answer (score 6):

I have used the *United States International Alternate* keyboard layout ([altinter.zip](https://keyboards.jargon-file.org/altinter.zip)) to my satisfaction for years now.

It moves the dead keys to AltGr+key combinations, meaning:

- <kbd>'</kbd> → '
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> → "
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> → á
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> → Ä
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> → è

Although the real winner for typing accented characters is to use their regular, non-dead US-international AltGr shorthands.

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> → Ä
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> → ß
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> → ü
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> → ö

Note: several people have had the same idea, there are multiple copies of this concept.
https://keyboards.jargon-file.org/
https://chris.charabaruk.com/2014/10/alternate-us-international-keyboard-layout/
https://github.com/thomasfaingnaert/win-us-intl-altgr

Answer (score -1):

It happens in Windows and any other OS.

When we use "US International" *and* we need special characters for the our non-English input language we take advantage of the "dead keys" feature.

That means if you want double-quotes you need to press the key once followed by space. Not using the space will be interpreted as "dead key" and accentuate the next character typed resulting in an umlaut (**ü** instead of **"u**...).

It's just a matter of adapting your typing technique like I did - I use a few US Int keyboards for languages like Spanish, Portuguese and French, each one requiring a lot more special characters than German.

Comment: "Just get used to it" is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This answer is also not true.
US Internationa Layout in Linux does not need space for quotes, etc to appear. This is mainly a "windows thing.".

Comment: No, other operating systems have a no-dead-keys option.

Comment: I can say that as of 2022 neither Gnome/Android using US Intl. layout behave like Windows 10