# Is there a keyboard shortcut to add a non-breaking space in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

We have a number of staff/ clients using Chrome to manage various Content Management Systems (i.e. Squarespace, Shopify, Silverstripe, Wordpress etc.)

In some cases the users want to add a non-breaking space. For example they might want `Our Company Limited` to not break in a new line:

> Our Company
>
> Limited

In HTML this can be done by writing `Our&nbsp;Company&nbsp;Limited` but many of the users aren't technically savvy or can't enter raw HTML into their CMSs.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts they can use to enter a non breaking space into a text box in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operating system specific keyboard shortcuts. They work in most applications, including Chrome.

**Linux**: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`u`, `a0`, `Space`

Explanation: press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`u`; then type `a0`; then press `Space` or `Enter`

**Windows**: `Left Alt` + `255`

Explanation: Hold `Left Alt`; while holding it, type `255` on the number pad; release `Left Alt`

**Mac OS**: `Opt` + `Space`

I haven't tested the Mac OS one (do not have Mac on hand), but Wikipedia suggests it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods

Comment: Confirmed that the MacOS one works (and continues to work)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can implement an [AHK script](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for such shortcuts.

With [my project (see this topic)](https://superuser.com/a/1519376/1131496), you can type a non-breaking space as :

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.